Long running PHP script get terminated and other separate PHP cmd line processes as well
Env: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS PHP 8.1 CMD line scripts started with the & and left to run in the background
I have 3 separate PHP scripts which I started from an SSH session and are placed in the background via &. The first two mostly sleep and check redis periodically. The third one has more complicated steps which involves API calls and database write operations.
The third one runs for about 2/3 hours and then all of a sudden my SSH sessions freezes and then when I log into the server all 3 separate PHP processes dissapear.
The server is not running out of memory since this is the output of free -h when all 3 scripts are running.
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1.9Gi       521Mi        62Mi       8.0Mi       1.3Gi       1.2Gi
Swap:             0B          0B          0B

My understanding is that there is 1.2gigs of memory available and that can't be the issue.
There are other PHP scripts which run periodically via CRON but even if they were to error out, they are completely separate. They also do not share any code.
PHP max_execution_time is set to 0
Is there such a thing as a PHP CMD line process/session cleaning job which PHP runs periodically and that could cause this? Or maybe some sort of global timeout across PHP command line processes. Maybe something related to the SSH session freezing. However all those processes are in the background via &.
Has anyone had this issue?
Thanks

Why not just try to run in within screen and log what happens? and by the way a 3 hour running php process what kind of application is that?

@djdomi thanks for the screen idea, i'm not interested in this solution. I just ran the command this way to include all errors in the file: "php8.1 script.php &> logfile &" we will see what it reports when it stops again. There are some API quota limits so the script sleeps quite a bit to deal with that.
